# PHP oop Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception:

Tags: php, soap, ssl

I cannot connect to my website with my orange server, this error is coming up:

I've enabled ssl and soap but it still doesn't work.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR:
Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://m2mconnect.orange.co.uk/orange-soap/services/MessageServiceByCountry?wsdl':
Start tag expected, '<' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\library\connect.class.php:10

Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\library\connect.class.php(10): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://m2mconn...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\application\views\items\homepage.php(20): Connect->__construct()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\library\template.class.php(30): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\library\controller.class.php(25): Template->render()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\library\shared.php(91): Controller->__destruct()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\library\shared.php(91): callHook()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\library\bootstrap.php(4): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\public\index.php(8): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#8 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\library\connect.class.php on line 10
```

Comment: `Start tag expected, '<' not found` should be pretty clear? I would look in the source code that gets downloaded, there might be an error in there.

Answer (score 1):

Try saving the WSDL to a local file, and reference that in your constructor...

```
$client = new SoapClient('/local/path/to/wsdlfile.wsdl');
```

Edit: if you're getting http errors while using the filesystem, you're doing something wrong :-)

Tried to run this myself, and these are my responses.
Note: I've had trouble connecting to the orange server as well, might be that their https connection is somewhat smelly...

Var-dump a fresh SoapClient:

```
$> php -r "var_dump(new SoapClient('https://m2mconnect.orange.co.uk/orange-soap/services/MessageServiceByCountry?wsdl'));"
PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://m2mconnect.orange.co.uk/orange-soap/services/MessageServiceByCountry?wsdl' :
 failed to load external entity "https://m2mconnect.orange.co.uk/orange-soap/services/MessageServiceByCountry?wsdl"
 in Command line code on line 1
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://m2mconnect.orange.co.uk/orange-soap/services/MessageServiceByCountry?wsdl' :
 failed to load external entity "https://m2mconnect.orange.co.uk/orange-soap/services/MessageServiceByCountry?wsdl"
 in Command line code:1
Stack trace:
#0 Command line code(1): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://m2mconn...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in Command line code on line 1

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://m2mconnect.orange.co.uk/orange-soap/services/MessageServiceByCountry?wsdl' :
 failed to load external entity "https://m2mconnect.orange.co.uk/orange-soap/services/MessageServiceByCountry?wsdl"
 in Command line code:1
Stack trace:
#0 Command line code(1): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://m2mconn...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in Command line code on line 1
```

Wget'ing the WSDL:

```
$> wget https://m2mconnect.orange.co.uk/orange-soap/services/MessageServiceByCountry?wsdl -O MSBC.wsdl
--19:41:45--  https://m2mconnect.orange.co.uk/orange-soap/services/MessageServiceByCountry?wsdl
           => `MSBC.wsdl'
Resolving m2mconnect.orange.co.uk... done.
Connecting to m2mconnect.orange.co.uk[213.52.171.155]:443... connected.

Unable to establish SSL connection.

Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Downloading WSDL through browser, and using that one:

```
$> php -r "$s = new SoapClient('MSBC2.wsdl');var_dump($s, $s->__getFunctions());"
object(SoapClient)#1 (2) {
  ["_soap_version"]=>
  int(1)
  ["sdl"]=>
  resource(6) of type (Unknown)
}
array(11) {
  [0]=>
  string(133) "int sendMessage(string $username, string $password, string $deviceMSISDN, string $message, boolean $deliveryReport, string $mtBearer)"
  [1]=>
  string(116) "ArrayOf_xsd_string getDeliveryReports(string $username, string $password, string $deviceMSISDN, string $countryCode)"
  [2]=>
  string(122) "ArrayOf_xsd_string readMessages(string $username, string $password, int $count, string $deviceMsisdn, string $countryCode)"
  [3]=>
  string(100) "boolean flushMessages(string $username, string $password, string $deviceMSISDN, string $countryCode)"
  [4]=>
  string(139) "ArrayOf_xsd_string waitForMessage(string $username, string $password, int $timeout, string $deviceMSISDN, int $msgref, string $countryCode)"
  [5]=>
  string(204) "int sendMessageWithValidityPeriod(string $username, string $password, string $deviceMSISDN, string $message, boolean $deliveryReport, string $mtBearer, string $binarySmsDcs, string $validityDaysHoursMins)"
  [6]=>
  string(164) "int sendBinarySmsMessage(string $username, string $password, string $deviceMSISDN, string $message, boolean $deliveryReport, string $mtBearer, string $binarySmsDcs)"
  [7]=>
  string(162) "ArrayOf_xsd_string sendAndWait(string $username, string $password, int $timeout, string $deviceMSISDN, string $message, boolean $deliveryReport, string $mtBearer)"
  [8]=>
  string(193) "ArrayOf_xsd_string sendBinarySmsAndWait(string $username, string $password, int $timeout, string $deviceMSISDN, string $message, boolean $deliveryReport, string $mtBearer, string $binarySmsDcs)"
  [9]=>
  string(122) "ArrayOf_xsd_string peekMessages(string $username, string $password, int $count, string $deviceMsisdn, string $countryCode)"
  [10]=>
  string(142) "ArrayOf_xsd_string getDeliveryReportsFromDate(string $username, string $password, string $deviceMSISDN, string $countryCode, string $fromDate)"
}

$>
```

Please note that I can't call any of the methods, since I don't have valid details for it.

Comment: now i have this error Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http headers in

Answer (score 1):

> [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR:
>   Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from ...

Assuming the WSDL and service is actually accessible on the Internet, this means your script could not connect to the remote web service - it couldn't download the WSDL and it couldn't call the service. You need to check your server's network connectivity (particularly outbound). You might need to ask your host because their firewall/config could be stopping the outbound connections.